# No student/s knew the answer.

Tags: word-usage

No student/students knew the answer.

Which noun should I use?

Comment: In English the following would sound odd as Ricky correctly pointed out: 1) *No people knew the answer* (NO), or, 2) *No person knew the answer* (NO). But in English you can say: 3) *Nobody knew the answer* (singular)  and 4) *None of the people knew the answer* (plural). But the *real* question is "why".

Comment: "No person knew the answer" sounds fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ricky has given some useful (and more idiomatic) alternatives. However both your versions are possible in grammatical terms depending  on which definition of 'no' you use.

> Full Definition of NO
>
> 1a :  not any  ...
>   2 :   not a  ...
>
> **[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no)**

No students knew the answer. ---> Not any students knew the answer.

No student knew the answer. ---> Not a student knew the answer.

The former would more likely be seen in a written report than heard in conversation. The latter sounds somewhat formal these days but it is still grammatical.

Answer (score -1):

None of the students knew the answer.
Not a single student knew the answer.
No student of yours would know the answer.
No French student would know the answer to this, and if they did, they wouldn't admit to it.

And so forth. Your version is awkward. I don't know why.

Mari-Lou A suggests: "Not one student knew the answer."

Comment: You can also add to the list: *Not one student knew the answer*  if you like.

Comment: Although this is a very useful list of idiomatic alternatives, it isn't an answer to the  question.  It doesn't address the *reasons* for choosing 'student' or 'students' in the original versions. The fact is that 'student' may only be a dummy argument here. Just because the sentence might sound 'awkward' doesn't  mean that every sentence with a similar structure would.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: No, but this one does.

Comment: Sounding awkward is a matter of opinion. We are discouraged from answering in terms of opinion on Stack Exchange.   An answer would address the grammatical differences between the singular and plural use which is what the question was about. You haven't done that at all.   I'm sure you could do that by making use of your alternative versions and that could make it a good answer.